# Swift: How to nest a UITableView with varying table row counts inside a UICollectionView cell?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

The viewcontroller conforms to four protocols:

```
class transferResultsViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
}
```

The UICollectionView contains 4 cells:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 4
}
```

And a simple implementation:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCellForTransferResults

    // Labels of cells are set up here --> irrelevant for question

    return cell
}
```

There is a TableView nested in the CollectionView cell with 1 section:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

**THE PROBLEM**: The nr. of tableview rows inside all four collectionView cells can be accessed through an array:

```
let nrOfRowsArray = [2, 3, 2, 1] // e.g. the 1st collectionnviewcell has a tableview embedded that contains 2 row
```

How can I return the numberOfRows inside the tableview for each collectionviewcell?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { 
    var numberOfRows = ? // How to store the correct value here?
    return numberOfRows
}
```

And make it return the correct cellForRowAtIndexPath?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "identifier"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! nestedTableViewCell

    // Labels of cells are set up here --> irrelevant for question

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your tableView datasource and delegate methods, you need some way to determine which collectionViewCell the tableView is in.  There are several ways, but the easiest is probably to use the tableView's `tag` property to indicate the collectionViewCell's `item`.

Presumably your `CollectionViewCellForTransferResults` has a `tableView` property.  When you dequeue a collectionViewCell, set the `tag` like this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCellForTransferResults
    cell.tableView.tag = indexPath.item

    // Labels of cells are set up here --> irrelevant for question

    return cell
}
```

Now in your tableView datasource and delegate methods, you can test the `tag` property of the `tableView` parameter to determine the collectionViewCell.  For example:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let tvTag = tableView.tag 
    let numberOfRows = nrOfRowsArray[tvTag]
    return numberOfRows
}
```

and

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "identifier"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! nestedTableViewCell

    // Labels of cells are set up here --> irrelevant for question
    let tvTag = tableView.tag 
    // configure the cell for the row given by indexPath.row in
    // the collectionViewCell given by tvTag

    return cell
}
```

This should work OK provided

1. You have only one section in your collection view (otherwise there might be several collection view cells with the same `item`, albeit in different `sections`); and
2. You do not add/delete collection view cells (since the `tag` on the other tableViews can end up out of sync with the collection view `item` value).